# How to get the parameter from the URL after '/'

Tags: java, rest, url, servlets, postman

https://localhost:8080/invoice_creation/1/

Here /invoice_creation is my resource location and /1 is my invoice number which denotes my database. I want to parse the value 1 alone in my java servlet when I pass this URL in my postman. I've used request.getParamerter() method..but it doesn't help me.. please help me to parse the value 1 in my java servlet page

Comment: I think that you should put some code snippet to let us see the problem.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: @MaurineiMiranda-No

Comment: @KamikazeJones How is a Javascript issue helpful to a Java Servlet issue?

Answer (score 2):

`getParameter` is for the `x` and `y` in for example: `http://localhost:8080/invoice_creation/1?x=5&y=hello`.

A webserver listens on port 8080, receives the 'location' that the visitor wishes to visit (such as `/invoice_creation/1?x=6&y=hello`), and needs to then **route** this by finding the 'handler' that is supposed to deal with this. It then calls that handler.

Java has a ton of web frameworks, and most cooked up their own way of routing.

The 'original' java web servers uses the servlets API. It's a crappy API that you shouldn't be using; it's a pain to use. But, given that you tagged this question with `servlets`, you are, evidently, using it. I suggest you look around; perhaps Jersey/JaxRS is nicer, especially if you're attempting to set up a REST API.

At any rate, if you insist on using the servlet API, you've somehow set up routing such that `/invoice_creation/_anything goes here_` ends up at some servlet and now you wish the 'anything goes here' part. Exactly how to do that depends on a few factors, but usually its one of these:

- `req.getPathInfo()`. Depending on your Web Server / servlet container you're using, this will either return `/1` or returns `/invoice_creation/1`. You'll have to 'extract' the 1 from this, using either regular expressions (`java.util.regexp.Pattern` and friends), or basic string manipulation such as `str.substring`).
- `req.getTranslatedPath()`.
- `req.getRequestURI()` - this definitely returns the whole thing (including `/invoice_creation/`).